# Uninstalling .NET 7.0

Tags: c#, .net

Let me preface this saying I have a M2 MacBook.
I have accessed the external uninstaller (here: https://github.com/dotnet/cli-lab/releases)
Final commands from Microsoft are not working (here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/additional-tools/uninstall-tool?tabs=macos#step-1---display-installed-net-sdks-and-runtimes)

I finally got access to the uninstaller through Terminal and tried using some of the commands from the second link. It just spits back that it is an unrecognized command to everything. I want it to uninstall the .NET 7.0.

[image: My Terminal rn]

Comment: You might want to check this out: https://devkimchi.com/2021/11/24/removing-dotnet-sdks-from-macos-manually/

Comment: The shell won’t run a program on the command line without a path, so if `dotnet-core-uninstall` is in the current directory, the command would be `./dotnet-core-uninstall`.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you have the `dotnet-core-uninstall` tool in a directory named 'dotnet-core-uninstall' and that the directory is not in the PATH.

To run an executable that is not in the PATH but is in the current directory, you need to be explicit about the location of the executable and use `./`, e.g `./dotnet-core-uninstall`.

The following is correct:

```
./dotnet-core-uninstall -h
```

As you show in your screenshot, this command works and displays the help. The help shows that the usage of the command is:

dotnet-core-uninstall [options] [command]

You can't use an option for the command without the command, e.g. `--help` should be `./dotnet-core-uninstall --help`.

The command to list should be:

```
./dotnet-core-uninstall list
```

The command to get help on dry-run is:

```
./dotnet-core-uninstall dry-run --help
```

Dry runs for 7.0 for SDK and runtimes are the following commands:

```
./dotnet-core-uninstall dry-run --major-minor 7.0 --sdk
```

```
./dotnet-core-uninstall dry-run --major-minor 7.0 --runtime
```

If the dry runs look correct, change `dry-run` to `remove` and use `sudo` to run as admin.

```
sudo ./dotnet-core-uninstall remove --major-minor 7.0 --sdk
```